# Loading saved_model causes "Failed to compile fragment shader" for gather op

Tags: tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I'm using Tensorflow in Python to define and train the model, and then I save it to a saved_model and load it on a website using TensorflowJS. I've made a minimal working example presented below, and have isolated the issue to the gather op. I'm using Windows 7 x64, Python 3.5.2, numpy 1.15.1 (forced upon installing tensorflowjs - had 15.2 before that) and the latest version of tensorflowjs installed using simply `pip install tensorflowjs`. The browser is Chrome, and it's all served on localhost using Wamp.

Step 1: Python

```py
# coding=utf-8

import tensorflow as tf
import sys
import os, shutil

x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[5], name='x')

#pred = tf.transpose(x, name="y") # THIS WORKS
pred = tf.gather(x, 1, axis=0, name="y") # THIS DOES NOT - thus must be related to the gather op

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(pred, feed_dict={x: [0,1,2,3,4]})) # just to check that it works in Python
    tf.saved_model.simple_save(sess, "./export", inputs={"x": x}, outputs={"y": pred})
```

Step 2: tfjs-converter command

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=tf_saved_model --output_node_names="y" --saved_model_tags=serve export C:/wamp/www/avatar/web_model
```

Step 3: Serving the website:

```html
<!-- index.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" />
  <title>test</title>
  <script src="./ext/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```js
// script.js

async function learnLinear() {
  const model = await tf.loadFrozenModel('http://localhost/avatar/web_model/tensorflowjs_model.pb', 'http://localhost/avatar/web_model/weights_manifest.json');

  x = tf.tensor1d([2, 3, 4, 1, 1], "int32");

  model.execute({
    "x": x
  }); // "x: The input data, as an Tensor, or an Array of tf.Tensors if the model has multiple inputs."
}
learnLinear();
```

The error produced is:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Failed to compile fragment shader.
    at createFragmentShader (tfjs:2)
    at e.createProgram (tfjs:2)
    at compileProgram (tfjs:2)
    at tfjs:2
    at e.getAndSaveBinary (tfjs:2)
    at e.compileAndRun (tfjs:2)
    at e.gather (tfjs:2)
    at ENV.engine.runKernel.$x (tfjs:2)
    at tfjs:2
    at e.scopedRun (tfjs:2)
```

And above that in the console there's:

```
ERROR: 0:157: 'getIndices' : no matching overloaded function found
157          setOutput(getA(int(getIndices(resRC))));
```

So getIndices is missing, and it's not declared in the tfjs script that's imported, only called...

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tf.gather` has parameters `indices` of type tensor. And this is the case both in [python](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/api_docs/python/tf/gather) and in [js](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.13.0/#gather)

To avoid your error, you have to change the following:

```
pred = tf.gather(x, tf.constant([1], dtype="int32"), axis=0, name="y")
```

After building the graph again and converting it to a frozen model you will be able to use it in js.

Comment: gather is allowed to take a scalar as well (including a native number). This was an issue in TF.js that is resolved in the latest version.